# Prove $ S $ is a unitary transfornation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

Let $ S : \mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathbb{C}^3$ be an invertible linear transformation such tha $ S^{-1} + S + 2I = 0 $.  I need to find all possible eigenvalues of $ S$ and prove whether $ S $ is unitary or not. Is my proof correct?

Let $ \lambda $ be an eigenvalue of $ S $. Therefore, there exists a $ v \neq 0 $ such that $ Sv = \lambda v$.

$ S = -S^{-1} - 2I \Rightarrow (-S^{-1} - 2I)v = \lambda v \Rightarrow S^{-1}v = (-\lambda - 2)v \Rightarrow v = \lambda(-\lambda - 2)v \Rightarrow 1 = -\lambda² - 2\lambda \Rightarrow \lambda = -1$.

Let $ S $ be the linear transformation defined by $ Sv = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}v $.

Let $ E $ be the standard basis. Therefore, $ [S]_E = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Therefore, $ [S^{-1}]_E = [S]_E^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow [S]_E + [S]_E^{-1} + 2I = 0 \Rightarrow S + S^{-1} + 2I = 0$.

$ E $ is an orthonormal basis with respect to the standard inner product, and therefore, if $ S $ were unitary, then $ [S]_E $ would be unitary too, but the norm of the third column is $ \sqrt{2} $, which means it is not.

Therefore, the transformation is not necessarily unitary.

Comment: Note explicitly in your argument that you simply have to exhibit an example of a linear map satisfying the hypothesis and not unitary, so that it is clear what you are doing: help your reader! «In order to show that the answer to the second part is negative, let us exhibit an example such that...»

Comment: Your proof is fine. But a slightly simpler argument is to observe that the matrix $S$ satisfies $(S+I)^2=0,$ therefore the only possible eigenvalue is equal $-1.$ Moreover the condition $A^2=0$ is satisfied by any nonzero  nilpotent matrix of order $2.$ Clearly $S=-I+M$ is then nonunitary.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I can't really see how $ (S+I)^2 = 0 $.

Comment: $S+S^{-1}+2I=S^{-1}[S^2+2S+I)$